# Looking for R function that enumerates all 3x3 tables with specified margins

Tags: r

Ideally something like f(rowMargins=c(3,10,2),colMargins=c(4,8,3)) that outputs a list of all the 3x3 tables with these margins.

Comment: What is your expected out put? May be it is worth looking into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example in order to improve question

Answer (score 1):

This generates 100,000 such tables randomly and then picks out the unique ones giving in this case 54 such tables.

```
set.seed(123)
tabs <- unique(r2dtable(100000, c(3,10,2), c(4,8,3)))
length(tabs)
## [1] 54
```